# SSH keys are added to default location and not to specified AuthorizedKeysFile in sshd_config

Tags: ssh

I want to change the location where the Authorized SSH keys are saved. Therefore, I changed the location of the authorized keys file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u/authorized_keys
```

The ssh service was restarted with `sudo systemctl restart ssh` and the owner and group of the `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/user` directory is the right user/group.

The server is accessible for the already included ssh keys in `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/user/authorized_keys`, but adding a new ssh key from some other device to the server with `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@server` saves the key in the default directory `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Grateful for any advice or help!

Comment: what is the question here exactly?

Comment: I want that all Authorized Keys are saved in the location `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u/authorized_keys` as specified in the sshd_config file.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming by this later, ssh-copy-id is on the client, and the sshd_config is on the server. It cannot know where to write to. It assumes the default location.

Furthermore, you don't want every user able to write into /etc/ssh/authorized_keys anyway. If you've specifically set ownership to the user for /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/user then there's no obvious benefit vs having it in the default location. The advantage of doing what you've suggested is for centralized management of keys, an advantage you only have if the users are NOT permitted to write to it.